# Java - Same Object, Different variables, Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

I am writing some code where

```
class A {
    Integer x;
    String y
}
```

I created an object of A and I am passing it to 2 runnable threads. First thread updates value x, while second one updates value y.

Is there any scenario where this can break? I mean, can there be a race condition if there are two threads updating different variables of the same object?

Comment: why do you need single object then? pass different objects to different threads

Comment: Yes, there are many scenarios where this can break. You need to read http://jcip.net/

Comment: Which thread is _reading_ the data?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will work fine.  As long as any given variable is only updated by one thread (With some conditions on the reading of that variable by other threads) you will be okay.

It may not be the most comprehendible design depending on what you are doing--Also, as I alluded to above, don't count on reading those variables from another thread reliably, if you want that look into atomic objects or volatile. (Atomic will be quicker for writes from multiple threads, volatile may still be better if you are just writing from one thread and reading from others)

Comment: This answer feels like a handwave: The "some conditions on the reading of that variable by other threads" is the most important part! There are lots of non-obvious behaviors that can occur in the scenario described, depending on exactly where `x` and `y` are *read*, which is the important part here.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is not only about race conditions it's also about memory visibility formulated by
[jsr-133](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) which you absolutely have to learn if you want to understand concurrency in java.

There are probably many ways in which your code can break, one obvious example is if you create your object in Thread A change x in thread B and y in thread C you might never see those changes in Thread A.

Some code to illustrate:

```
A a = new A();
a.x = 0;

Thread t1 = new Thread( () -> {
    while (true) {
        a.x = 1;
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread( () -> {
    a.y = "a";
});

t1.start();
t2.start();

while(a.x == 0) {
}

System.out.println("might never get here");
```

One possible fix is to make x and y volatile

```
class A {
    volatile Integer x;
    volatile String y;
}
```

This will ensure that all threads see changes to x and y but you still need to make sure that the instance of A is safely published.

Comment: @BillK "If the author is simply writing different variables from two threads, he's fine" **absolutely not!!!** Without making sure that writes will be seen correctly he will end up with unexpected behavior and incorrect values. I made up a scenario that conforms to his question and breaks(well at least can break, it will be difficult to actually see it happen).